# Streaming output to stdout, in-place status updates to stderr

Tags: c, printf, stdio

I have a program that should produce output on `stdout`, and transient status information on `stderr`. Programs with similar results might include rsync or apt (though their output is sufficiently complex that reducing it to the essentials I need is daunting).

This program *seems* like it should work as described, but does not:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

void *work () {
  for (long i = 0; i < LONG_MAX; i++) {
    if (i % 100000000 == 0) {
      fprintf(stdout, "%ld\n", i);
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "\rrunning %ld", i);
  }

  return 0;
}

int main() {
  work(0);
  fprintf(stderr, "\ndone\n");
  return 0;
}
```

The status info is updated in place via `stderr` as desired, but only a single line of output appears via `stdout`. If the `stderr` status `fprintf` is removed, then all `stdout` output appears as expected.

What is going on here?

Comment: Try fflush(stdout) and fflush(stderr) after each print.

Comment: That won't help.  stdout is line buffered by default, and there is a newline after outputs to stdout, and stderr is unbuffered by default.

Answer (score 1):

This code is correct (well, the void * return from work() is bad form--void would be far better).

I suspect that the problem is simply that you are not waiting long enough--it takes time to iterate through 100,000,000 iterations, especially with output each time through the loop (remember--you will be blocking on output once you fill the stdout buffer).

I estimate it will take a minimum of 3 minutes before you get the second output to stdout.

Comment: Point taken re: form, but I'm far from my actual expertise. :-) However, no, if you comment out the `stderr` `fprintf` line, you'll see results rapidly, ~5 lines/second on my laptop.

Comment: That makes sense--the thing that's taking all the time is the output of 100,000,000 numbers to stderr before you get to the second number written to stdout.

Comment: Re: form, the problem with your declaration is work() is declared to return a pointer but you are returning an int (C compilers special-case 0 so you can treat it as a pointer without getting an error; if you change return 0 to return 1 it won't compile).  Because you don't actually use the return value, you would be far better served declaring the routine as void and not returning a value.  This func is simple enough that it doesn't really matter, but if you keep writing C, someday you will be very happy to get a compile error instead of needing to debug.

Comment: You're right about the time of the output to stderr in that example. Unfortunately, it's what I thought was a minimal case demonstrating a failure I'm seeing in a much larger program. I'll see what I can do to update the question to actually reproduce the problematic behaviour I'm seeing.